# subset xts object out of a time period

Tags: r

I have got a large xts object containing quite a lot observations. I know that it is possible to get the data in certain time periods using x["yyyy-mm-dd/yyyy-mm-dd", "yyyy-mm-dd/yyyy-mm-dd", "yyyy-mm-dd/yyyy-mm-dd"]. But how can I delete the data in those time periods and get the rest?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: What did you try so far? Plese read SO guidelines about good asking: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

you can use dplyr in this fashion:

```
require(dplyr)

df%>%filter(- xtsColumn > date1 & xtsColumn < date2)
```